# Django while returning values shows list out of index

Tags: python, django, list

I am trying to return values to a template using request method in a view. The values are in a list. When i try to access these values in return I get a list out of index error. But the values are proper when I print these values to a cmd.

Error

```
IndexError at /
list index out of range
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.11.20
Exception Type: IndexError
Exception Value: list index out of range
Python Version: 2.7.15
```

views.py file

```
def index(request):
    req_val = [None]
    demo_text =[]
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        req_val.append(request.POST.get('val1'))
        req_val.append(request.POST.get('val2'))
        req_val.append(request.POST.get('val3'))
        demo_text = package_name.classobj(req_val[0],req_val[1],req_val[2]).methodprintval() 
        print demo_text  #sample output: [1,2,3]
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'sampleval1':demo_text[0],'sampleval2':demo_text[1],'sampleval3':demo_text[2]}) #error list index out of range
```

I tried finding solution but couldn't. How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show where you are accessing this list?

Comment: I am accessing the list values here ```demo_text```:
return render(request, 'index.html',{'sampleval1':demo_text[0],'sampleval2':demo_text[1],'sampleval3':demo_text[2]})

Comment: Well I can't understand what you mean about this line `demo_text = package_name.classobj(req_val[0],req_val[1],req_val[2]).methodprintval()`.

Comment: Calling a function methodprintval() of class classobj and passing values to it

Comment: In your `index.html`, how are you accessing the list?

Comment: Like {{sampleval1}} {{sampleval2}}

Comment: Can you show the output of `demo_text[0], demo_text[1] and demo_text[2]`?

Comment: When I print values of demo_text i am supposed to get [1,2,3] which it does. But when render it's throwing an list out of index error

Comment: Maybe `demo_text[0], demo_text[1],...` does not contain any data? Have you tried printing the value of them?

Comment: Maybe you need to post the `methodprintval()` of the class you have defined.

Comment: Yes sanip i have. it has values which it shows properly.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you taking an extra overhead when you can directly pass the value in context.I am not sure what you **methodprintval** does.

```
dict(zip([f'sampleval{i}' for i in range(1,4)],req_val))
```

this would generate you context var by itself

```
{'sampleval1': 1, 'sampleval2': 2, 'sampleval3': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Request Method: GET`

`if request.method == 'POST':`

when method is GET your list is empty.